# Tikz plot - set origin for plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am trying to position a parametric curve within a tikzpicture.
Using the following code, I the curve is plotted with the centre at (0,0), but I would like the centre to be positioned at (0,5) so that the parametric curve touches the circle.
I've looked up `plot` in the tikz documentation; using `\addplot` from `pgfplots`; positioning at `node`s and `path`s, all to no avail, the curve remains with centre (0,0)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=10];
%
\draw [domain=0:360, samples=300] plot ({-5 * sin(\x) * (sin(\x/2))^1.2 }, {-5 * cos(\x)});
%
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

How can I specify where the centre of the plot is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Add `(0,5)` to the plot (note the number `5` starting the y coordinate of the plot).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=10];
\draw [domain=0:360, samples=300]
  plot ({-5 * sin(\x) * (sin(\x/2))^1.2 }, {5-5 * cos(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Solution 2:** Shift the center of the circle down by `5`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,-5) circle [radius=10];
\draw [domain=0:360, samples=300]
  plot ({-5 * sin(\x) * (sin(\x/2))^1.2 }, {-5 * cos(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Solution 3:** Use a scope and shift its contents, either the circle or the plot.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=10];
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,5)}] % or [yshift=5cm]
  \draw [domain=0:360, samples=300]
    plot ({-5 * sin(\x) * (sin(\x/2))^1.2 }, {-5 * cos(\x)});
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

All solutions yield the same picture.

[image]

Comment: thanks, fiddling with tikz made me forget about the most basic of transformations!